# Finding the PDF of a transformed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let
$$
f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases}  4x, \qquad 0 \le x < \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{8}{7}-\frac{4}{7}x, \qquad \frac{1}{4} \le x \le 2 \\ 0,\qquad \mathrm{else} 
\end{cases}
$$

If $Y=X^2$, how can I find the PDF of Y? I don't believe I can partition the pieces because their y-components would not be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the fact that your rv is non-negative, the transformation $Y=X^2$ is monotone. Thus simply use the well known formula

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
f_Y(y)=f_X[g^{-1}(y)]\Bigg|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\Bigg|
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

leading immediately to

$$f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
2,  & \text{ $0\leq y<\frac{1}{16}$ } \\
\frac{4}{7\sqrt{y}}-\frac{2}{7}, & \text{ $\frac{1}{16} \leq y \leq 4$ }\\
0, & \text{elsewhere }\\
\end{cases}$$

... without doing any integral but simply substituting $g^{-1}(y)$ and its derivative in formula (1)

**Check:**

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_Y(y)dy=2\times \frac{1}{16}+\int_{\frac{1}{16}}^{4}\Bigg[\frac{4}{7\sqrt{y}}-\frac{2}{7}\Bigg]dy=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{7}{8}=1$$

nice! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the CDF. For $t\in[0,16]$:

$$F_Y(t)=\Pr(Y\leq t)=\Pr(X^2\leq t)=\Pr(X\leq \sqrt{t})=\int\limits_0^{\sqrt{t}} f_X(x)dx$$

It is left to finish the integral and differentiate if you want the PDF.

Comment: @325 : the given $f(x)$ is not a density....didn't you read my answer below?

Comment: 325 Yes, you either need one integral (from 0 to $\sqrt{t}$) or two integrals, from 0 to 2 and from 2 to $\sqrt{t}$.
@tommik , the given $f(x)$ is not normalized but that can be easily fixed with the right factor. I guess it's just a typo.

Comment: @YJT I fixed the density. How would I go about this one? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Same. If $\sqrt{t}<0.25$ there is only one integral, otherwise you have to split it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X \ge 0$.
$$
F_Y(y)
 = \mathbb{P}[Y \le y]
 = \mathbb{P}[X \le \sqrt{y}]
 = F_X(\sqrt{y}).
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: didn't you check the text before answering? The given $f(x)$ is not a density

Comment: @tommik I am sure it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys but there is something wrong in the text...

...the given density is a triangle with area $\frac{4\times 1}{2}=2$

thus the given $f_X(x)$ is not nice...

Comment: I fixed the density. How would I go about this one? Sorry for the confusion.